# bar chart starting over line chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to overlap a line and a bar graph. The tricky part is that the bars shouldn't start at 0, but at the line. So far I tried

```
valuation <- c(100, 105, 120)
deposit <- c(0, 10, -15)
date <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2010-11-2','2010-11-3'))
df <- data.frame( valuation, deposit, date)ggplot(df) + 
        geom_line(aes(x=date, y=valuation, group=1)) + 
        geom_col(aes(x=date, y=deposit, fill=sign)) + 
        scale_fill_manual(values = c("positive"="green","negative"="red"))
```

That produces the following output: https://i.ibb.co/pyT3bk2/1.png (sorry I need 10 reputation to post images)

I need the positive values to start on the same point of the line and go up, and the negative values to also start over the line but go down: https://i.ibb.co/gZBsXnp/2.png

Do you know if this is possible?? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: what is group=1?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `geom_col` I would recommend using `geom_rect` here:

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=date-.4, xmax=date+.4, ymin=valuation, ymax=valuation+deposit, 
                fill=ifelse(deposit>0, "positive", "negative"))) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=date, y=valuation)) + 
  ylim(0, 120) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("positive"="green","negative"="red"), name = "sign")
```

creating the following graph:
[image]

Comment: yessssssssssssssss it works perfectly. Thanks a lot Wietse!!!